# Using SUHD TV for conference views

Tags: skype, raspberry-pi, tv, camera, chromecast

I apologize in advance if this is the wrong sub to be asking this question in, but it didn't seem fitting for Hardware Recommendations or Server Fault.

A couple of months ago I bought 3 Samsung 65" 4k TVs for my NPOs 3 office locations where the idea was to set up each location with Skype/Camera using the built-in Multi-Screen feature. (I've used this on my own TV at home which is why I opted for this)

The place I bought the TVs from gave me a good price ($1050 each) and promised these features would be available, but apparently it looks like they're not after all.

The TVs in question are the Samsung UE65KU6075U(XXE). On my own TV at home, I simply plug in the camera into a USB slot on the back of the TV and start Skype while I can also use Multi-Screen to open a browser and run a camera in another room in that view.

What are my options to get this to work? I preferably don't want a laptop for example sit and delegate this, would something like this be possible with a Raspberry Pi or Chromecast/Apple TV or similar?

Comment: https://eltechs.com/run-skype-on-raspberry-pi/   ?

Comment: Yes, that's something I was looking at while asking this question which is why I included the PI. Do you think that's my best choice?